# Use Regex to obtain 3 pieces of information from a table in C#

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am new to Regex. I am managing to get somewhere but I cannot combine 3 records.

This is my sample html that I download as String:

```
   <table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Валута</th>
         <th>Код</th>
         <th>За единица валута</th>
         <th>Фиксинг на БНБ</th>
         <th>Курс купува</th>
         <th>Курс продава</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Австралийски долар</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">AUD</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.21074</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.18700</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.23320</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Канадски долар</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">CAD</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.27010</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.23650</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.28450</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Швейцарски франк</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">CHF</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.82107</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.78300</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.85290</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Китайски юан</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">CNY</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">10</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">2.44534</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">2.31970</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">2.54220</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Датска крона</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">DKK</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">10</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">2.62707</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">2.57830</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">2.67830</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Евро</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">EUR</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.95583</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.94900</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.95850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Британска лира</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">GBP</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">2.17182</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">2.11490</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">2.19700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Японска йена</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">JPY</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">100</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.59399</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.55580</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.61620</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Норвежка крона</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">NOK</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">10</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.86388</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.82700</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.89900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Нова румънска лея</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">RON</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">10</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">4.04164</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">3.85620</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">4.22380</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Руска рубла</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">RUB</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">100</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">2.41212</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">2.25600</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">2.54400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Шведска крона</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">SEK</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">10</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.91018</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.87410</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.94790</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Щатски долар</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">USD</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.70919</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.67080</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">1.71890</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get the value in the second td from each tr, the third value from each tr and the last value from each tr.

After hours of playing with diferent things so far I got this:

```
>\b[^>]*>(.*?)
```

this matches only the information in the td along with ">" and along with the closing td tag. Also it gets all of them.

Comment: HTML is NOT regular so using Regex (regular expressions) are not recommended and you should use an HTML library so parse the data.

Comment: I downoload this html as a string.  And I need to write code for each website. Most sites for currency data use similar data with tr and td.

Comment: It just means you are reading a table which is easy to read with a library.

Comment: Are there any libraries that you can recommend?

Comment: See following : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9b86d4/getting-started-with-html-agility-pack/

Answer (score 1):

Add package [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/).

Open namespace

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

Try this code

```
var html = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
            
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var trs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody/tr");

foreach (var tr in trs)
{
    var tds = tr.SelectNodes("./td");

    var code = tds[1].InnerText;
    var quantity = tds[2].InnerText;
    var sale = tds[5].InnerText;

    Console.WriteLine($"{code}  {quantity,3}  {sale}");
}
```